# How can two files on a CD-ROM have the same inode number yet have a link count of 1?

Tags: filesystem, directory, iso

As I was doing some sorting of my collection of CDs, I found out that processing the output of a `find` with `sort -u` was giving me a smaller list than plain `sort`, so I investigated. Using `diff` on the outputs, I found out the name of the repeated file, and I went to actually check how the same file can exist twice. Indeed, the file that was being repeated, `32`, exists twice in `fonts/basic`. The filesystem is *ISO9660*:

```
root@user-desktop:/mnt/loop/fonts/basic# ls -al
total 22
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root  2048 1978-07-01 00:47 .
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 12288 1978-07-01 00:48 ..
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  3884 1978-07-01 00:47 32
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  3884 1978-07-01 00:47 32

root@user-desktop:/mnt/loop/fonts/basic# ls -l -i
total 8
203394 -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 3884 1978-07-01 00:47 32
203394 -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 3884 1978-07-01 00:47 32
```

OK, so they are hardlinked because they have the same inode, but how can they have the same name?  And why do they report only having one hardlink?

```
root@user-desktop:/mnt/loop/fonts/basic# mount|grep mnt/loop
/dev/loop0 on /mnt/loop type iso9660 (ro)
```

Can anybody think of an explanation? Is it something about the *ISO9660* filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a plain *ISO9660* filesystem:

```
mkdir cd
echo 'hello world' > cd/foo
echo '42' > cd/bar
genisoimage -o cd.iso cd
```

Mount, examine, and unmount it:

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter cd.iso
ls -li /media/user/CDROM
 1474 -r--------  1 user  user     3 Jul 18 19:38 bar
 1475 -r--------  1 user  user    12 Jul 18 19:38 foo
umount cd.iso
```

Now open the image in a hex editor, and replace `FOO.;1` with `BAR.;1`.  If it's helpful, the inode numbers on my system are really the offset of the directory entry into the ISO image / 32, i.e. look at around `python -c 'print hex(inode*32)'`.

*ISO9660*, like *FAT*, doesn't have inodes, but Linux pretends it does.  All information is stored directly in the directory, and as each variable length entry is at a minimum more than 32 bytes, this guarantees all 'inodes' are unique.

Now remount it and look again:

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter cd.iso
ls -li /media/user/CDROM
 1474 -r--------  1 user  user     3 Jul 18 19:38 bar
 1474 -r--------  1 user  user     3 Jul 18 19:38 bar
umount cd.iso
```

Notice the 'inode' numbers and file sizes.  Both files are still there in the image, but the duplicate filename confuses Linux, causing it to list the first file twice.  The second file is completely inaccessible now anyway.